# entering a country with two passports

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I am traveling to India and I hold two passports from two different countries. Is it ok for me to enter India with one passport and then leave the country and next time to enter with my other passport.I would appreciate if someone could shed a light on this issue. Thank you!

Comment: What's your motivation to do this?  If it's to get around visa or entrance limitations, note that the limits apply by person not by passport, so this could cause you some problems.

Comment: While there are reasons to do this, those that do know exactly why and exactly what rules to follow.  That you're even asking suggests this isn't the case.

Comment: I have a US passport and Nepalese passport. I am flying from the US and I am not sure which passport i should use at indian immigration. If I show my Nepal passport they will ask where I am coming from and then I am to tell them I am US citizen as well since there is no visa on my Nepalese passport.  I am worried that they might give me a hard time since Nepal does not recognize dual citizenship. Actually its easier for me to enter India with Nepalese passport because India allows free movement to Nepal citizens.

Answer (score 1):

If you acquired the US citizenship by naturalization, [you are not a Nepalese citizen anymore](http://www.refworld.org/docid/3ae6b51914.html):

> Article 9 Termination of Nepali Citizenship
>
> (1)  The Nepali citizenship of any Nepali citizen shall automatically
>   lapse on his acquiring the citizenship of any foreign country of his
>   own will.

And thus you cannot legally use the Nepali passport. While the implementation of such provisions is often questionable[*], having some experience with Indian immigration I'd expect at least major hassle.

[*] India, for example, has the same provision in law. But in reality one has to go through a special procedure to surrender the Indian passport, which also costs $175.